# How do I loop through an array and stop at a certain index

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

So, I have an array of 7 numbers, 0-6. I want to loop through it for a certain amount of times and stop at a certain index or number. For instance, the program starts at 0 and I want to loop it 12 times and have the program output 4. Another instance, the program starts at index 2 and loops 10 times. The output should be index 5. How do I do this and is it possible?

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi, please be more precise and clear about what the problem is and also share what you have tried so far. Here is a [guide about how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple loop that controls how you cycle through the array.

Example:

```java
int arr[]; // Our array
int t; // How much to cycle through the array
/**
* Some code to set a value for t and fill arr
**/

int index = 0; // The final index. Initally 0 to prevent undefined case  t <= 0

for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
   if (index == arr.lenght) {index = -1;} // -1 so whe don't need to have an else clause
   ++index;
}
```

If you want to start in a position different than 0 in the array just create some code to set *index* before the loop and remember to check if *index* is less than the array lenght

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the modulo `%` operator. This allows you to skip the loop and immediately land on the final index entry. This operation is constant and should be preferred if you dont have to actually cycle through the indeces until you land on the final number.

For you two examples you can see two print statements for each case:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int n = arr.length;
    int t = 12;
    //case 1
    System.out.println(arr[t%n]);

    //case 2
    int index = 2;
    t = 10;
    System.out.println((t + index)%n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "If the program *(iterations)* starts at 0 *(index)* and I want to
> loop it 12 times and have the program output 4".

Okay, I get that. You start your count as literal 1 from index 0:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12   (on the 12th iteration starting from Index 0)
-------------------------------------
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2   3   4    (element value at index)
-------------------------------------
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2   3   4    (array index)
```

> "Another instance, the program starts at ***index* 2** and loops **10**
> times. The output should be index **5**".

This one confuses me:

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10     (on the 10th iteration starting from Index 2)
-----------------------------------
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2  3  4      (element value at index)
-----------------------------------
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2  3  4      (array index)
```

The output should be index **4** as well, not index **5**.

Anyway, here's another way this can be accomplished:

```
int startIndex = 0;                     // The INDEX value to start iterations from.
int loopNumOfTimes = 12;                // The literal number of desired iterations.
int[] array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};    // The Integer Array (length 7).
int counter = 0;                        // A counter used to count literal iterations.
int i;                                  // Decalred outside of loop so its value can be used.
// Iterate through the Array
for (i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
    counter++;  // Increment counter.
    // Have we reached the desire number of iterations?
    if (counter == loopNumOfTimes) {
        // Yes...Break out of loop.
        break;
    }
    /* Reset the 'for' loop if we've reached actual array length (length minus 1).
       i++ in the 'for' loop is automatically applied once the first iteration is 
       complete and every iteration thereafter as long as 'i' remains less than 
       the literal length of the array. Because we are applying a value change to 
       'i' so as to start the loop form 0 again (a loop reset) the i++ will be 
       immediately be applied which takes 'i' to 1 istead of the desired 0. This 
       is no good so we set 'i' to -1 that way when i++ is applied 'i' is set to 
       0 and iterations start again from that index value.                  */
    if (i == (array.length - 1)) {
        i = -1;
    }
}
    
// Display the Array element value located at index 'i'.
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

In the above code you can see that the Start Index (***startIndex***) is **0** and the Desired Number Of Loops (iterations) held in the ***loopNumOfTimes*** variable is **12**. The output to console window will be: **`4`**.

If you change the ***startIndex*** value to **2** and the ***loopNumOfTimes*** value to **10** then the console window output will be: **`4`**.